# Differentiate between Server Side and Client Side on fetch Sapper

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, sapper

Sapper gives you the ability to preload that runs on both client and server side.

```
<script context="module">
    export async function preload(page, session) {
        const res = await this.fetch(`blog.json`);
        const article = await res.json();
        return { article };
    }
</script>
```

How would I distinguish between a server side call and a client side call?

In `Nuxt` the context provides `isServer` and `isClient` to differentiate.
Is there one for `sapper`?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried to catch the error

```js
let isServer;

try {
    let win = window;
    isServer = false;
} catch (e) {
    isServer = true;
}
```

PS: I actually found the solution in svelte [kit Docs](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#modules-$app-env)

```js
import { browser } from '$app/env';

// browser is true or false depending on whether the app is running in the browser or on the server
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe some variables such as `process.browser` or the global `window` variable are only available on the client side, so you should be able to use these to determine whether your code is running on the client or the server.

Within the *regular* `<script>...</script>` tags, you can also use Svelte's `onMount` lifecycle function to execute code that will only run on the client (i.e. when the component is actually mounted).

Comment: It threw an error on server side when I even referenced window, as in `if (window)`  (tried this before) `onMount` is not ideal since you can't stop the preloading when it's client sided, therefore you end up fetching twice.

Answer (score 0):

Just an update, for SvelteKit 1.0.0 and later...

The [`environment`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment) module includes the [`browser`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/modules#$app-environment-browser) property, which returns `true` if being run client-side.

For example,

```js
import { browser } from '$app/environment';

if (browser) {
  // Running client-side
  // Can use the browser APIs here
} else {
  // Running server-side
  // Can use private env vars here
}
```